# left-align with .css file works partially in RMarkdown

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I have this code in .css file

```
.column-left{
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Then applies it to RMarkdown

```
<div class="column-left">

This is a sentence.

* This is a sentence.
* This is a sentence.

</div>
```

However, only text with bullet points is left-aligned.

[Image of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKnRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
float: right;
```

this is the cause of the inconsistency of your expected result.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I removed the float: right; and still had the same issue. I also tried to keep text-align: left; only. It didn't work.

Comment: can you make sure that there is no rule for direction: rtl; within the body element?

Comment: No, there are no other rules.

Comment: Hi I just notice when I knit the R Markdown, the HTML will be set as text-align: center; automatically. The solution is to edit HTML files directly after building the website.